C++17: explicit first template parameter before variadic template
I am trying to write a generic class for a symmetric bloc matrix of arbitrary dimension. Only the upper triangular part is given:
A B C
  D E
    F

so the number of blocks is n*(n+1)/2 where n is the dimension (3 here).
A possible implementation with variadic templates is (I used integers for the blocks, for the sake of simplicity):
#include <tuple>
#include <cstddef>

template <size_t Dimension, typename... Blocks>
class SymmetricBlockMatrix {
public:
    constexpr SymmetricBlockMatrix(Blocks... blocks): blocks(blocks...) { }

    constexpr size_t dimension() const {
        return Dimension;
    }

protected:
    const std::tuple<Blocks...> blocks;
};

int main() {
    constexpr SymmetricBlockMatrix<3, int, int, int, int, int, int> m(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
    return 0;
}

I would of course check that the number of blocks is consistent with the dimension.
Is it somehow possible to provide only the dimension explicitly and let the compiler infer the types of the blocks? Then I could write:
int main() {
    constexpr SymmetricBlockMatrix<3> m(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
    return 0;
}

This results in the following compiler error:
error: no matching function for call to 'SymmetricBlockMatrix<3>::SymmetricBlockMatrix(int, int, int, int, int, int)'
   18 |     constexpr SymmetricBlockMatrix<3> m(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);


Partial CTAD like syntax is not allowed.

CTAD lets you write SymmetricBlockMatrix m(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) but I'm unsure if that's what you need without explicitly specifying N.

Makes sense, thanks! I wrote another version of the code where the dimension is not provided but computed based on the number of blocks.

Use the old helper method make workaround and make use of auto

Can types be different from each others?

BTW, you might use full CTAD (not specify 3 at all neither) with some math.

Indeed! But I think it's good to have that information explicitly. Yes, the blocks can have different types. I ended up implementing the class with a helper function, works like a charm.

One workaround is to use the old make helper function template trick along with auto as shown below:
//this is a helper
template <size_t V, typename... T>
constexpr SymmetricBlockMatrix<V, T...> make_SymmetricBlockMatrix(T... t)
{
    return SymmetricBlockMatrix<V, T...>{t...};
}
int main() {
    constexpr SymmetricBlockMatrix<3, int, int, int, int, int, int> k(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
    constexpr auto m = make_SymmetricBlockMatrix<3>(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6); //works now 
   
}

Working demo

Oh that's brilliant, thanks! I sort of had an intuition that partial template argument deduction was possible (hi std::make_unique), now I understand that it's possible for functions, not classes.

I started a Git repo where I implemented a basic symmetric block matrix: https://github.com/cvanaret/SymmetricBlockMatrix
It uses the helper function described by @user12002570: we can now specify the dimension of the matrix as a template parameter, enforce static tests and let the compiler infer the types of the blocks:
template <size_t Dimension, typename... Blocks>
constexpr SymmetricBlockMatrix<Dimension, Blocks...> symmetric_block_matrix(Blocks... blocks) {
    // check that the number of blocks is consistent with the dimension
    static_assert(sizeof...(Blocks) == (Dimension*(Dimension + 1))/2, "The number of blocks is not consistent with the dimension.");
    
    return SymmetricBlockMatrix<Dimension, Blocks...>{blocks...};
}

The next challenge is to condense the linear system (= eliminate row blocks) at compile time using Schur complements.
